# Illuminated Cloud Retrieval Scope

Tags: illuminatedcloud, intellij

The issue I am encountering is when trying to Retrieve Metadata. I have new classes in my Salesforce ORG that aren't being downloaded to my project in IntelliJ via Illuminated Cloud 2. I have read the documentation (http://www.illuminatedcloud.com/home/deployment) and I am using Retrieve.

What I am hoping to understand is the different options for "Contents" in the "Select Retrieval Scope". If someone could explain those, I would appreciate it as I couldn't find documentation around it.

I currently have it set to "Context" (which has been working in the past for other projects) and see my classes listed among many others. Once I hit Retrieve though, I get this message:

```
4:47 PM Retrieve Complete
                Retrieved the following files:


4:47 PM Retrieval Complete: No components were retrieved.
```

I also tried "Custom" and only selected my classes but I got the same message.

I finally selected "Project" and that one added everything from the org into the project and I was able to see them despite the following message:

```
4:52 PM Retrieval Complete: Retrieved 0/58 components from <org_name> 
     in 4 m 40 s 984 ms with status SUCCEEDED.
```

My connection subscription has "All/Package" selected so I would've expected to retrieve the classes regardless of the selected option for "Contents" under the retrieval scope.

Thanks!

Comment: did you click the "refresh" icon before Retrieving?  BTW - IC2 support gets near immediate attention on IC2 [Google Group](https://groups.google.com/a/illuminatedcloud.com/forum/#!forum/qanda)

Comment: That's what I was doing originally but it seems that wouldn't retrieve new files as per the documentation: "Note that this option cannot be used to retrieve metadata which does not already exist locally".